# Can I use FileSystemObject get a single file from a folder using its index?

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject, fso

If there is only one file in a folder, can I pick it up **without** knowing its name or iterating through the files in the folder?

(The code is VBS, but it could be anything, the FSO is the interesting part here.)

This didn't work for me:

```
dim fso
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim myFolder
Set myFolder = fso.getFolder("E:\test")
Dim myfiles
Set myfiles = myFolder.Files

WScript.Echo myfiles.Item(0).Path
```

Neither did `WScript.Echo myfiles(0).Path` work. (Index 0,1 tested, both fail.)

Using a for each to get just one file seems a bit of an overkill. Also, am I not supposed to be able to somehow iterate with a simple `For` loop, not a `For Each`? So there must be indexes... I just can't seem to find them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't pick the file without knowing its name or iterating over the files in the folder, at least not with a `FileSystemObject` instance. As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779003.aspx) the `Item` property of the `Files` collection requires the *name* of an item, not its index:

> **Item Property (Files)**
>
> Gets the specified item for in a Files object
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> object.Item(key)[ = newitem]
> ```
>
> **Arguments**
>
> *object*
>   Required. The name of a File object.
>
> *spec*
>   Required. The name of the item.

Not every collection allows access by index.

If you're looking for a magic trick you could do something like this:

```
dir = "C:\your\folder"

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ex = sh.Exec("cmd /c dir /b """ & dir & """")
While ex.Status = 0 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend

filename = Split(ex.StdOut.ReadAll, vbNewLine)(0)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFile(fso.JoinPath(dir, filename))
```

However, that approach is neither very elegant nor very robust, and I fail to see its advantage over something like

```
dir = "C:\your\folder"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each item In fso.GetFolder(dir).Files
  Set f = item
Next
```

Comment: Wow. So I can't even use a simple For loop, only For Each. Thanks. I'll leave this open for a while, maybe someone has a magic trick.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible by using [Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) objects, just like you thought.

```
dim shellApp
set shellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
dim myFolder
Set myFolder = shellApp.NameSpace("E:\test")
Dim myfiles
Set myfiles = myFolder.Items 'also contains subfolders

WScript.Echo myfiles.Item(0).Path

'and for loop
Dim i
For i = 0 To myfiles.Count - 1
    WScript.Echo myfiles.Item(i).Path
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely sure that there's only one file in the folder, a single line of code should do it for you:

`Set MyFile = FSO.GetFile("E:\test\" & Dir("E:\test\"))`

...at least it works for me in Excel VBA.

Comment: Very good idea! Unfortunately, the `Dir` command doesn't work like this in VBS. Thanks for the idea though, nice. :)